# What can I do to my contract to work with BEP20 mainnet

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I'm trying to make an ICO for my Token.
I wrote the code and its worked.
The problem is I can only buy coins with ETH but I want to launch my token in the BEP20 network so people will need to send BNB to the contract to get the token.
Because of this will be the private ICO I dont want to do with 3rd party sites.
Can someone help me?
Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

interface ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) external view returns (uint balance);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) external view returns (uint remaining);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) external returns (bool success);
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}


// The Cryptos Token Contract
contract Cryptos is ERC20Interface{
    string public name = "Cryptos";
    string public symbol = "CRPT";
    uint public decimals = 0;
    uint public override totalSupply;
    
    address public founder;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    // balances[0x1111...] = 100;
    
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;
    // allowed[0x111][0x222] = 100;
    
    
    constructor(){
        totalSupply = 1000000;
        founder = msg.sender;
        balances[founder] = totalSupply;
    }
    
    
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view override returns (uint balance){
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }
    
    
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public virtual override returns(bool success){
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= tokens);
        
        balances[to] += tokens;
        balances[msg.sender] -= tokens;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        
        return true;
    }
    
    
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view override returns(uint){
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }
    
    
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public override returns (bool success){
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= tokens);
        require(tokens > 0);
        
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public virtual override returns (bool success){
         require(allowed[from][to] >= tokens);
         require(balances[from] >= tokens);
         
         balances[from] -= tokens;
         balances[to] += tokens;
         allowed[from][to] -= tokens;
         
         return true;
     }
}


contract CryptosICO is Cryptos{
    address public admin;
    address payable public deposit;
    uint tokenPrice = 50000000000000000 ;  // 1 ETH = 1000 CRTP, 1 CRPT = 0.001
    uint public hardCap = 3000000000000000000000000000000 ;
    uint public raisedAmount; // this value will be in wei
    uint public saleStart = block.timestamp;
    uint public saleEnd = block.timestamp + 604800; //one week
    
    uint public tokenTradeStart = saleEnd + 604800; //transferable in a week after saleEnd
    uint public maxInvestment = 5000000000000000000000000000 ;
    uint public minInvestment = 1;
    
    enum State { beforeStart, running, afterEnd, halted} // ICO states 
    State public icoState;
    
    constructor(address payable _deposit){
        deposit = _deposit; 
        admin = msg.sender; 
        icoState = State.beforeStart;
    }

    
    modifier onlyAdmin(){
        require(msg.sender == admin);
        _;
    }
    
    
    // emergency stop
    function halt() public onlyAdmin{
        icoState = State.halted;
    }
    
    
    function resume() public onlyAdmin{
        icoState = State.running;
    }
    
    
    function changeDepositAddress(address payable newDeposit) public onlyAdmin{
        deposit = newDeposit;
    }
    
    
    function getCurrentState() public view returns(State){
        if(icoState == State.halted){
            return State.halted;
        }else if(block.timestamp < saleStart){
            return State.beforeStart;
        }else if(block.timestamp >= saleStart && block.timestamp <= saleEnd){
            return State.running;
        }else{
            return State.afterEnd;
        }
    }


    event Invest(address investor, uint value, uint tokens);
    
    
    // function called when sending eth to the contract
    function invest() payable public returns(bool){ 
        icoState = getCurrentState();
        require(icoState == State.running);
        require(msg.value >= minInvestment && msg.value <= maxInvestment);
        
        raisedAmount += msg.value;
        require(raisedAmount <= hardCap);
        
        uint tokens = msg.value / tokenPrice;

        // adding tokens to the inverstor's balance from the founder's balance
        balances[msg.sender] += tokens;
        balances[founder] -= tokens; 
        deposit.transfer(msg.value); // transfering the value sent to the ICO to the deposit address
        
        emit Invest(msg.sender, msg.value, tokens);
        
        return true;
    }
   
   
   // this function is called automatically when someone sends ETH to the contract's address
   receive () payable external{
        invest();
    }
  
    
    // burning unsold tokens
    function burn() public returns(bool){
        icoState = getCurrentState();
        require(icoState == State.afterEnd);
        balances[founder] = 0;
        return true;
        
    }
    
    
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public override returns (bool success){
        require(block.timestamp > tokenTradeStart); // the token will be transferable only after tokenTradeStart
        
        // calling the transfer function of the base contract
        super.transfer(to, tokens);  // same as Cryptos.transfer(to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
    
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public override returns (bool success){
        require(block.timestamp > tokenTradeStart); // the token will be transferable only after tokenTradeStart
       
        Cryptos.transferFrom(from, to, tokens);  // same as super.transferFrom(to, tokens);
        return true;
     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `payable` modifier of the `invest()` function allows to send the main token of whichever network is the contract deployed on.

So if it's on Ethereum network, users can send ETH along with the transaction invoking the function.

If it's deployed on the BSC network, users can send BNB along with the transaction invoking the function.

If it's deployed on the Tron network, ... they can send TRX.

etc.

Comment: thank you for your info